# ConnectionSpecWrapper no longer present in recent releases

Tags: activejdbc, javalite, activeweb

Why the activejdbc class ConnectionSpecWrapper has disappeared in recent releases?

in the 3.0 (and also 2.3.2-j8) activejdbc jar we have:

```
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionJndiConfig.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionConfig.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionJdbcConfig.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionDataSourceConfig.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/DBConfiguration.class
```

In 2.3 jar we have

```
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionSpecWrapper.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/DbConfiguration.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionJdbcSpec.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionSpec.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionDataSourceSpec.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionJndiSpec.class
```

I am using it like this, in a filter:

```
@Override
public void before() {

    if(Configuration.isTesting())
        return;

    List<ConnectionSpecWrapper> connectionWrappers = getConnectionWrappers();

    if (connectionWrappers.isEmpty()) {
        throw new InitException("There are no connection specs in '" + Configuration.getEnv() + "' environment");
    }

    for (ConnectionSpecWrapper connectionWrapper : connectionWrappers) {
        DB db = new DB(connectionWrapper.getDbName());
        db.open(connectionWrapper.getConnectionSpec());
        log.debug("Opened connection: " + connectionWrapper.getDbName() + " envname " + connectionWrapper.getEnvironment());
        if(manageTransaction){
            db.openTransaction();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void after() {
    if(Configuration.isTesting())
        return;

    List<ConnectionSpecWrapper> connectionWrappers = getConnectionWrappers();
    if (connectionWrappers != null && !connectionWrappers.isEmpty()) {
        for (ConnectionSpecWrapper connectionWrapper : connectionWrappers) {
            DB db = new DB(connectionWrapper.getDbName());
            if(manageTransaction){
                db.commitTransaction();
            }
            db.close();
            log.debug("Closed connection: " + connectionWrapper.getDbName() + " envname " + connectionWrapper.getEnvironment());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of upgrading the Gazzetta dello Sport's fantasy football site which has been live for something like 8 years and working really well. It is on Java 7/Activeweb 1.10/Activejdbc 1.4.9

Answer (score 0):

The "wrapper" classes have been renamed into "Spec" classes, as you rightly noticed. Generally these classes are not used. If you want to continue  using them you can of course (rename accordingly). However, a better approach is to define  your connections in a  file:

https://javalite.io/database_configuration#property-file-configuration
 and simply use https://javalite.io/controller_filters#dbconnectionfilter.

I'm assuming you wrote a custom controller filter and are using [ActiveWeb](https://javalite.io/activeweb).

Update:

Now that we established you use ActivewWeb, consider removing  your code and simply using a `DBConnectionFilter`, here is a perfect example: https://github.com/javalite/javalite-examples/blob/master/activeweb-simple/src/main/java/app/config/AppControllerConfig.java#L31

Comment: Yes it's a custom controller filter and i'm using active web.

Comment: But I need to do an equivalent thing on the latest releases, which do not have those classe.

Comment: These are the classe in the latest releases:

Comment: org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionJndiConfig.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionConfig.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionJdbcConfig.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionDataSourceConfig.class
org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/DBConfiguration.class

Comment: you can just rename these classes min your custom controller. The rest should work as before.

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks, but what should I rename the ConnectionSpecWrapper class to?

Comment: I reckon there is a mismatch between the java docs and the actual jar in the repo. The javadoc: http://javalite.github.io/3.0-SNAPSHOT/org/javalite/activejdbc/connection_config/ConnectionSpecWrapper.html mentions the class "org.javalite.activejdbc.connection_config.ConnectionSpecWrapper", but it is not present in the jar.

Comment: @JeremyColeman, sorry about JavaDoc, it was not updated. It is now updated, so your link is dead. Instead of replicating the code in DBConnectionFilter, why can't you just use the filter? In case you still want to do this, you can borrow code from: https://github.com/javalite/javalite/blob/master/activeweb/src/main/java/org/javalite/activeweb/controller_filters/DBConnectionFilter.java. In all seriosness, why not delete all this code and just do it the way we recommend: https://github.com/javalite/javalite-examples/blob/master/activeweb-simple/src/main/java/app/config/AppControllerConfig.java?

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for that. I think I will delete that custom filter, because I don't need it any more. Was using it in the past to connect to different oracle schemas. If I remember well, I think you helped me do it. But now I'm no longer using it because the requirement for opening different schemas is no longer  current. I'll check out your links.

Comment: @JeremyColeman,  in that case, feel free to upvote and mark this answer as correct. Also, keep in mind, that you can in fact access multiple databases without writing custom code. You can add multiple `DBControllerFilter` configurations.